# al ejecutar el index me genera este error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al ejecutar el index me genera este error  estoy trabajando con entity framework 6

mi web.config

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="bsBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="214748647" maxBufferSize="214748647" maxReceivedMessageSize="214748647" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

mi controlador para generar mi index es el siguiente:

```
public class RRHH_MUNICIPIOController : Controller
{
    RRHH_MUNICIPIOClient db = new RRHH_MUNICIPIOClient();
    RRHH_DEPARTAMENTOClient dbDepto = new RRHH_DEPARTAMENTOClient();
    public RRHH_MUNICIPIOController()
    {
        mapa.Mapeo.CrearMapas();
    }
    // GET: RRHH_MUNICIPIO
    public ActionResult Index()
    {          
            IEnumerable<ent.RRHH_MUNICIPIO> listar = db.TraerTodo();
            IEnumerable<mod.RRHH_MUNICIPIOModel> entidad = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ent.RRHH_MUNICIPIO>, IEnumerable<mod.RRHH_MUNICIPIOModel>>(listar);
            return View(entidad);        

    }
```

mi proxy  es el siguiente:

```
 [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IRRHH_MUNICIPIO/TraerTodo", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IRRHH_MUNICIPIO/TraerTodoResponse")]
System.Collections.Generic.List<AplicacionEntidad.RRHH_MUNICIPIO> TraerTodo();
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: debes mostrar el código que genera este error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el mensaje de error que muestras parece que es problema de que los datos que te intentas traer tienen un tamaño superior a los 65536 bytes que te meustra el mensaje de error.

Para solucionar eso puedes atacarlos de dos maneras:

Por una parte en vez de "traerTodo", podrías hacer una paginación que no sobrepase el limite de datos establecido.

O podrías aumentar el limite de datos del binding que estes usando.
Para ello tienes que aumentar establecer un valor diferente al actual(65536) en la propiedad `MaxReceivedMessageSize` por ejemplo 1000000.

Si puedes poner tu app.config y el código donde te da el error podríamos ayudarte mejor

Comment: este es el que genera mi vista para traer todo  
        public ActionResult Index()
        {      
                IEnumerable<ent.RRHH_MUNICIPIO> listar = db.TraerTodo();
                IEnumerable<mod.RRHH_MUNICIPIOModel> entidad = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ent.RRHH_MUNICIPIO>, IEnumerable<mod.RRHH_MUNICIPIOModel>>(listar);
                return View(entidad);        
                      
        }

Comment: <binding name="bsBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="214748647" maxBufferSize="214748647" maxReceivedMessageSize="214748647" />

Comment: @rmonroy eso deberías ponerlo en la pregunta inicial para que lo podamos ver bien. Por otra parte podrías poner tambien el codigo de `db.TraerTodo()`